# laravel 5.3 and whatsapi could not find driver

Tags: laravel, whatsapi

i have proplem thats i installed fresh laravel project 
and i installed whatsapi 
to send whatsapp message from my project .. 
i flowed the steps on this link 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/xaamin/whatsapi)

but my proplem when i did this 
in my route 
like

```
Route::get('whats',function(){
      // Retrieve user data from database, web service, and so on.
// Dummy method, fake data.
$user = new stdClass;
$user->name = 'Benjamín Martínez Mateos';
$user->phone = '5219512222222';

$message = "Hello $user->name and welcome to our site";

$messages = Whatsapi::send($message, function($send) use ($user)
{
    $send->to($user->phone);




    // Add new text message
    $send->message('Thanks for subscribe');
});
});
```

I get this error:

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1
PDOException in SqliteMessageStore.php line 23:
could not find driver
in SqliteMessageStore.php line 23
at PDO->__construct('sqlite:C:\whatsapidemo\storage/whatsapi\msgstore-            962799024459.db', null, null, array('2', '2')) in SqliteMessageStore.php line 23
at SqliteMessageStore->__construct('962799024459',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by this error: `could not find driver`

Make sure you have the PHP SQLite PDO driver enabled on your server

Comment: the sqllite pdo is enabled and why i need it to send from whatsapp anyway cant i just change it to mysql and get the connection from env file ?

Comment: The server can't obviously find it as stated, please double check you did it right.